# Allocate Micropython array from a specific memory range

Tags: micropython

I'm using Micropython on an ESP32-S3.  I'm setting up DMA from an ADC by manually configuring the appropriate registers using mem32.  I need to reserve some space in the SRAM1 region of Internal RAM for the linked list of descriptors.  i.e. In address range 0x3FC88000 to 0x3FCEFFFF.

Is there something like array.aray() that lets me specify a range?

I assume either drivers or some other internal Micropython plumbing under the hood is already using some of that internal RAM address space, as I see non-zero values in it.  I want to make sure my code doesn't stomp on anything being used (or vice versa).